# Row_number not doing what i need (SQL) - Oracle 11G

Tags: sql, oracle11g, row-number

I'm using ORACLE 11G database

I have a table which have these columns:

```
item, cod_line, business, cod_business, cod_ez_catalog_product_brand, business_unit, last_update_date
```

It is called: **products_table**

Take a look (i'm filtering for a specific product):

```
SELECT item, cod_line, business, cod_business, cod_ez_catalog_product_brand, business_unit, last_update_date
from products_table
WHERE ITEM = '94TERFERE'
```

I'm getting this output:

[image]

I want to get only one row within the most update "last_update_flag" value, in this case this one:

[image]

I did this:

```
SELECT item, cod_line, business, cod_business, cod_ez_catalog_product_brand, business_unit, last_update_date
from
(
SELECT 
item, cod_line, business, cod_business, cod_ez_catalog_product_brand, business_unit, last_update_date,
row_number() over (partition by last_update_date order by last_update_date desc) as rnum
FROM XX_OTC_PRODUCTOS_OUT 
where item in ('94TERFERE')
and end_date_active is null
order by last_update_date desc
)sub
where rnum = 1;
```

But i am not getting 1 row, i'm getting 8 rows from 10 records available!:

[image]

Desired result:

[image]

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to partition by item, not last_updated_date

Comment: Yeah, i realized that but, why?

Comment: Could you please explain to me why should i use item instead of the other?

Comment: Because you are trying to apply row numbers to each group of records with the same item value. Think of the partition clause happening before the where clause - or remove the item column from the where clause - and how it works may make more sense